# How to run sequence mediator parallel

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to create the sequence to call 2 another sequence using sequence mediator on wso2 esb 4.0.3.
My sequence information like below:


    
        
            
                
                
            
        
    

When i try to run it. i have problem when the first sequence is error, the second sequence can't run.
I want when the first sequence is error, the second sequence can be run individually.
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [Clone mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Clone+Mediator) in WSO2 ESB. Below clone mediator configuration would split a message into two messages and those two messages will be sent to two sequences(test1 and test2). Then the messages will be processed in two sequences in parallel.

```
<clone>
    <target sequence="test2"/>
    <target sequence="test1"/>
</clone>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `<clone>` (like CHarithaM answered), but this will kill your transactions (i.e. JMS) etc. 
So I prefer to use a **JMS Topic with two consumers**. Then both of them have their own messageContext and run completely independently in a propper way.